# FFMpeg: convert any file (video/audio) to custom bitrate and dynamic range

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, flac, bitrate

So, in my specific case, I have a couple of FLAC files that are approximately 1500kb/s, and they are 24-bit. I want to convert them to 16-bit, and to make them around 500kb/s

I didn't find any info regarding changing that dynamic range, but I did find something in the `--help` dialog to change the bitrate, which didn't work for me, for some reason

```
ffmpeg -i in.flac -b:a 500k out.flac
```

This didn't do anything at all. The two files are the same size, and, just to check if I'm completely crazy, I even looked at their checksums. They're identical files somehow

So, what did I do wrong? And what can I do to also change that dynamic range? (convert from 16-bit to 24-bit)

Comment: Change in bitrate would only be a *result* of  (but not a cause / trigger to) a change in sample format in the case of lossless codec. Add `-sample_fmt s16`  (or something like  `-af aresample=osf=s16:dither_method=shibata` if you want some dithering) somewhere between `-i in.flac` and `out.flac`.

Comment: @TomYan Works better, meaning it isn't the same file anymore. It transforms it to 16-bit as I was asking for, but the bitrate isn't the one I asked for, like before. Original was 1844kbps, the normal conversion was 1087kbps, and the one with dithering is 1101kbps

Comment: You can't really just "ask for" a bitrate for lossless compression. You can at best [increase compression level](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44839083/5439097) and see how much it could help. If you need a file of a specific (average) bitrate, switch to a lossy codec like vorbis or opus.

Comment: @TomYan I don't want to switch to a lossy format, I just wanted to decrease the bitrate. I thought it is possible because I've had FLACs with 800 kbps, but also FLACs with 4000 kbps. Maybe I could give compression a try, but I have a question, does that decrease quality or just increase resource usage when playing the file (if I even understand well how audio compression works)?

Comment: The bitrate of FLAC depends on of the spec of the audio, compression level, and how "compressible" that specific track is (which is determined by various factors). AFAIK higher compression level does not increase the required computation power / time drastically / significantly on decoding, but only on encoding to a certain extent.

Comment: @TomYan So, just to be sure, before I try compression: it does not decrease audio quality, and it also decreases file size? Because decreased filesize was what I wanted to achieve initially with decreasing bitrate

Comment: FLAC is a purely *lossless* codec.